# JQuery getJson() passing object from

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have found similar questions to what I want to accomplish however I still don’t fully understand what I am doing incorrectly.

I want to return an array from the $.getJSON() Method and pass it into another function and then display the results.

So for example I have function one() with 2 variables such as name and country. These 2 variables are passed into function two() where they will be compared against data returned from an ajax request.

I then store the results as an array. But want to display the results in function one()

```
function one() {
    Var name = “bob”
    Var country = “UK”

    two(name, country)

   // Display the sheetsData array from function two() here
}

function two(name, country){

    Var url = “http://spreadsheets.google.com/.......”  

$.getJSON(url, {
    format: "json",
    async: false
}).done(function callback(json) {       

    var results = json.feed.entry;

    // Loop over json object that is returned from the URL
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        var gSheetName     = results[i].gsx$name.$t;
        var gSheetCountry  = results[i].gsx$country.$t;
        var gSheetPostCode = results[i].gsx$postcode.$t;
        var gSheetNumber   = results[i].gsx$number.$t;

        // If the name and country variables from one() matches with results 
        // from within GSheets the results will be stored in an array 
        if(name == gSheetsName && country == gSheetCountry ){

            var sheetsData = {
                "GSName": gsSheetName,
                "GSCountry": gSheetCountry,
                "GSPostCode": gSheetPostCode
                // etc.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

I tried the following but it obviously doesn't work. I'm guessing because the array sheetsData is within the call back function and not two()?

```
function one() {
    Var name = “bob”
    Var country = “UK”

    // Display the sheetsData array from function two() here        
    var fullResults = two(name, country)

   console.log(fullResults);

}
```

Comment: I know you're using `async: false`, but that's a problem in itself. You need to make the requests async, then provide a callback function to the `two()` function which you pass the response data to and execute after the AJAX request completes. See the duplicate I marked for more details.

Comment: Thank you Rory I somehow managed to miss that answer but have managed to figure out what i was doing wrong.